# Does a kineticist's telekinetic blast literally involve manually throwing a physical object?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, throwing-things, kineticist

Does a kineticist's telekinetic blast literally involve manually throwing a physical object?

[Telekinetic Blast](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/kineticist-elements/#Telekinetic_Blast) (*Occult Adventures*, p. 15) says:

> You throw a nearby unattended object at a single foe as a ranged attack. The object must weigh no more than 5 pounds per kineticist level you possess. If the attack hits, the target and the thrown object each take the blast’s damage. Since the object is enfolded in strands of aether, even if you use this power on a magic weapon or other unusual object, the attack doesn’t use any of the magic weapon’s bonuses or effects; it simply deals your blast damage. Alternatively, you can loosen the strands of aether in order to deal damage to both the object and the target as though you had thrown the object yourself (instead of dealing your normal blast damage).
>
> You substitute your Constitution modifier for your Strength modifier if throwing the object would have added your Strength modifier on the damage roll, and you don’t take the –4 penalty on the attack roll for throwing an object that wasn’t designed to be thrown. In this case, the object’s special effects apply (including effects from its materials), and if the object is a weapon, you must be proficient with it and able to wield it with one hand; otherwise, the item deals damage as a one-handed improvised weapon for a creature of your size.

I always thought it functioned much like the [Telekinesis](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/telekinesis/) spell using the Violent Thrust option:

> **Violent Thrust:** Alternatively, the spell energy can be spent in a single round. You can hurl one object or creature per caster level (maximum 15) that are within range and all within 10 feet of each other toward any target within 10 feet per level of all the objects. You can hurl up to a total weight of 25 pounds per caster level (maximum 375 pounds at 15th level).

This also has a weight limit of 5 pounds per level. Wouldn't that mean that you need X Str to be able to lift/throw bigger objects?

Also how does this affect the Physical and Energy Blast option of this ability?
How can you make a ranged touch attack with a physically thrown object?

Answer (score 2):

## No.

From [Telekinetic blast](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/kineticist-elements/#Basic_Telekinesis):

> Since the object is enfolded in strands of aether, even if you use this power on a magic weapon or other unusual object, the attack doesn’t use any of the magic weapon’s bonuses or effects; it simply deals your blast damage. *Alternatively, you can loosen the strands of aether in order to deal damage to both the object and the target* **as though you had thrown the object yourself** (instead of dealing your normal blast damage).

You use the blast to telekinetically throw the object. You are not physically throwing it yourself.